# zsh: command not found: pipenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pipenv, pipenv-install

even after installing pipenv 3x it is not working on my mac. If I use the command "python3 -m pipenv --version" I CAN see that it is installed (see below), however, if I go with "pipenv --version" the command is not found. My guess is that I messed something up with the path. Any idea how to solve this? thanks in advance!

**zsh output below**

```
user@users-MacBook-Air ~ % python3 --version
Python 3.11.4
user@users-MacBook-Air ~ % pip3 --version
pip 23.1.2 from
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
user@users-MacBook-Air ~ % python3 -m pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2023.7.4
user@userss-MacBook-Air ~ % 
user@userss-MacBook-Air ~ % pipenv --version           
zsh: command not found: pipenv
```

**my steps**:

- installed pipenv via pip with `pip3 install --user pipenv`
- uninstalled twice
- set the path with vi to "`export PATH="/Users/user/Library/Python/3.11/bin:$PATH`"

Comment: Editing your zsh login file to set the path will not affect your current session.  You need to log out and back in, for those changes to take effect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

using the --user is your mistake. After messing around in terminal, it told me that using it doesn't save it to a proper path. What worked for me was:

```
pip3 uninstall pipenv
y
pip3 install pipenv
```

this way your mac will automatically save it to a path

Comment: Thanks so much - this was the fix I needed 